# Yii hoauth account merge

Tags: php, yii, merge

I'm using the [hoauth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hoauth/) extension for user authentication and I want to make an optional account merge, where if a user logs in with a facebook account and a google+ account that have the same email they get asked to optionally merge those two accounts.
Currently when I try and login with a google+ account with an email that is already bound to a facebook account I get the following message:

> This E-mail address is taken by another user. If this is your account, enter password in field below or change E-mail address and leave password blank.

I want to remove this and add the optional merge and after merge they should be logged in, or if they chose not to merge the accounts I want to still allow them to login with that provider instead of showing this message.

I fount the piece of code that handles this, but what would be an effective way to achieve my goal.

`/extensions/hoauth/models/HUserInfoForm.php` is the location of `validateUser()` which handles the check.

I'm open to any and all suggestions, thank you.

Comment: but what happens if you enter the password? doesn't that merge the accounts as you wish? I haven't used hoauth, I used https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth which lets you handle user registration on your own, it's kind of tricky to work with but created my own user table and social_link table, so now one user can have multiple social_links from different providers.

Comment: I understand that if at this step the user changes the email, a new user will be created for that social account. So I think this already achieves what you want, but indeed with a different user interface.